# Access database from Asp.Net Core _Layout view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, controller

I want to add the option to select a component/module in my login form. I will like to call a GetComponents() method in my home controller that reads the component table, and returns a list to my Layout. I can then pass this list to my LoginViewModel to provide a list of available components for a user to choose when signing in. My system is such that I don't have a view in the Account folder, and so the Account Controller is not accessed before my modal bootstrap login form.

I need to have the listFromController value set before I instantiate my LoginViewModel in my Layout view as shown below.

```
public async Task<IList<SelectListItem>> GetComponents()
{
    var query = _context.Components.AsQueryable();
    return (await query.ToListAsync())
        .Select(d => new SelectListItem { Text = d.Name, Value = d.Id.ToString() })
        .ToList();
}
```

```cs
@await Html.PartialAsync(
    "LoginModal",
    new LoginViewModel { AvailableComponents = listFromController })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing the method in my Startup.cs, and setting the list property in my Configure method with something like  "myComponents = GetComponents();" at the end of the method.

```
private static IList<SelectListItem> GetComponents()
    {
        XDbContext _context = new XDbContext();
        var query = _context.Components.AsQueryable();
        return (query.ToList())
            .Select(d => new SelectListItem { Text = d.Name, Value = d.Id.ToString() })
            .ToList();
    }

    private static IList<SelectListItem> myComponents;

    public static IList<SelectListItem> ComponentList
    {
        get
        {
            return myComponents;
        }
    }
```

At around the top of my _Layout.cshtml, I added the following:

```
@{var listFromController = @Startup.ComponentList;}
```